# NSDate Format change depending on Language (region)

Tags: swift, swift2, nsdate, foundation

In my app (using Swift 2) I have a function that uses `NSDate`, however I have a problem : depending of the language set on the device the date obtained isn't the same (for example the months depends on languages : January in English is equal to Janvier in french)

When I have this :

```
NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(NSDate(), dateStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle, timeStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle.NoStyle)
```

When I'm localized in USA I get this format `3/29/16`
but when I'm localized in France for instance I get a different format : `29/03/16`

How can I ask for the same date format (here the American format) whatever the language is?

Comment: You should now that a locale is composed of the components - language and region. The language specifies how date units are translated (e.g. January, February in English opposed to Janvier, Fevrier in French). The date format does not come from the language, it comes from the region settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that you have to create your own date formatter like

```
let dateFormater = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormater.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yy"
let dt = dateFormater.stringFromDate(NSDate())
```

You can read more about the date format from [Date Format Patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns)

And [Date Formatting Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/)

Comment: This is not true. The NSDateFormatter takes user's locale into account unless you specify one. You can look at this page, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html which says following "Although in principle a format string specifies a fixed format, by default NSDateFormatter still takes the user’s preferences (including the locale setting) into account"

Comment: @GeneratorOfOne That will only affect, the calendar type and the 24 hr format. Please read the next two points of the same

Answer (score 5):

Use this,

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .NoStyle

dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
```

The key to having the same format is always using the same locale. So, it uses English locale to format the string and so it always remains in the format

```
M/d/yy
```